# How to make textbox text disappear when I click on it

Tags: c#, plsql, textbox, runtime

I managed to create textboxes dynamically in C#. When a `textbox` has text, can I make it disappear when I click on it?

I need to put a word inside textboxes that is the result of a select in Oracle.

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I googled for it,and I don't find any idea. I really don't know how can I create a textbox with a text inside of it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign a value to the Text property of the TextBox. You could subscribe then to the GotFocus event, and set the text value to an empty string.

```
// Holds a value determining if this is the first time the box has been clicked
// So that the text value is not always wiped out.
bool hasBeenClicked = false;

private void TextBox_Focus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!hasBeenClicked)
    {
        TextBox box = sender as TextBox;
        box.Text = String.Empty;
        hasBeenClicked = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

javascript is good for the delete.

```
onclick="$(this).val('');"
```

alternatively you can use HTML5 [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)